# Recording a script with instruments causes app to act differently?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, automation, instruments

I am trying to create automated tests for an app, but am running into a problem with instruments. A particular view consisting of a few text boxes which need keyboard input and a few that have a drop down menu pop up. Everything works perfectly fine when I am not trying to record anything with instruments but once I start recording, no matter which text box I tap, it always opens up the drop down menu in a particular text box. I have tried manually writing out the code for automation, but when I press play and the computer goes through and tries to tap on a text box, the same bug occurs. Anybody have any ideas as to why this app is working differently when instruments is running? Thanks